# Direct Input in C#

Tags: c#, directx, directinput

Hi guys im wanting to use direct input in my c# program so that I can interface with certain game controllers, however i've looked high and low and cant seem to find the

Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll

Can anyone link me to what package its in?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd install the [DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937788), and then reference it from that.

Comment: June the latest version?